# Vagrant public network between instances: high packet loss rate

Tags: networking, ping, vagrant

I have two vagrant instances setup and both running (host is macOS and vagrants are centOS7).

One is configured with public network ip 192.168.0.100 and the other is configured with public network ip 192.168.0.101

Now both can ping the host machine with ip 192.168.0.11 very quickly with 0 packet loss. Host machine can also ping both instances with 0 packet loss.

However when I ping between the two instances the packet loss rate is like 93% and takes seconds for even one response to come.

I tried adding the host 192.168.0.11 as default gateway like following but the packet loss rate does not change

```
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    run: "always",
    inline: "route add default gw 192.168.0.11"
```

EDIT:
In addition, this does not happen all the time, but it happens around 60% of the time when I reload the vagrant. Sometimes after like 30 minutes of pinging it miraculously becomes fast and lossless but then after another 30 minutes it becomes slow and lossy again.

In the slow case, traceroute gives 11 hops with everything except the final destination being "*".

Other machines in the same network can ping both instances easily as with zero loss well.

My guess is that some internal routing caused most requests to go into an infinite loop (because the two instances share the same ip for the 10.2.x.x address range automatically generated by vagrant but I am not sure). However I don't know how to start debugging this kind of case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

The vagrant machine sometimes added some bad Ip Table entries for unknown reason and the correct way to solve this issue is first use `ip route show table main` to get the Ip Table and then see if there is a line containing the high-loss address, then use `ip route del 192.168.0.0/24` to remove the entry. After that everything will work correctly.

EDIT:

The actual correct reason is because `arp` is not set correctly between instances. We need to `ifconfig` from one vagrant instance and get the mac address, then manually use `arp -s` to set the arp table in the other vagrant instance. After that everything will work correctly.

Ip routing table shall not be modified and removing the entry will cause one way to work correctly but the other direction unreachable. The correct way is to set the arp so both way will work correctlt.